# Django: Can't use session vars in ModelForm

Tags: python, django, session

I have this session var:

`empresa=request.session['codEmp']`

I have a ModelForm with a ModelChoiceField:

```
class AuxiForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tipAux = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=TipoAux.objects.all(), empty_label=None,
                                    required=True, to_field_name='codigo')
```

If you see the queryset for `tipAux` it's currently calling for **all** the `TipoAux` objects, but I really need to do a **filter**, calling only the `TipoAux` objects that have the same `empresa` attribute that the user has on his `codEmp` session var.

I tried by doing:

```
tipAux = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=TipoAux.objects.filter(empresa=request.session['codEmp']),
                                empty_label=None, required=True,
                                to_field_name='codigo')
```

But Django is not allowing me to use `request.session` in the form.

Any way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try overriding the form's `__init__()` method and pass the session variable in as an argument to the form:

```
class AuxiForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(filter_on, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AuxiForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['tipAux'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=TipoAux.objects.filter(empresa=filter_on), 
            empty_label=None,
            required=True, 
            to_field_name='codigo'
        )
```

And, in your `view.py`, you could say something like: `form = AuxiForm(data=request.POST, filter_on=request.session['codEmp'])`

Alternatively, you could use Django's generic [model view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/). If your form isn't more complicated than the one you posted—you'd just set the `queryset` attribute. (I'll leave the reading to you because I'm only just getting familiar with generic views myself.)